# How to get Column names Column Data types Form Table using Eclipse Link/JPA

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I am working on JPA. My requirement is get the Column Name and Data types from Table.
I have Query's to  do that but those are Native Query's. If I used those Native Query's, Is It will support on any Data Base like Oracle, MySql,......

Now am Using MySql with JPA working fine.

Below Query for Getting Table Column Names

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName'
AND   TABLE_NAME = 'TableName';
```

I executed above Query using **createNativeQuery()** in JPA . Is it will support in all Data Bases. If not then how can I do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` table and in MS SQL server and MySQL you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table to get information about tables and columns.

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE  OWNER = 'SchemaName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName';
```

Comment: I need a Query to support in any DataBase. Thank you

Comment: Because of you tagged `ORACLE` i answer the question in oracle, which `DBMS` are you work in?

Comment: Why because I need a Query to support in any DataBase. that's why I tagged. I explained also in my question.